# Within polygon region calculation

Tags: java, math, gps

I got the following code where I read GPS coordinates from a XML file then i want to check that my current location (lat and long) is within this polygon region... Not sure if am doing something wrong :( Look like my IsInsideRegion method is failing. Any advise welcome.

public class Point {

```
private double _latitude = 0d;
private double _longitude = 0d;

public Point() {
}

public Point(double aLatitude, double aLongitude) {
    _latitude = aLatitude;
    _longitude = aLongitude;
}

public Point(String pointData) throws Exception {
    FromString(pointData);
}

public static String ToString(Point point) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.append(point._latitude).append(",").append(point._longitude);
    return result.toString();
}

public void FromString(String pointData) throws Exception {

    String[] fields = pointData.split(",");
    if (fields.length != 2)
        throw new FormatException("Invalid input data: " + pointData + " in " + this.getClass().getName());

    _latitude = parseDouble(fields[0]);
    _longitude = parseDouble(fields[1]);
}

private double parseDouble(String aValue) {
    double result = 0d;
    try {
        result = Double.parseDouble(aValue);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    return result;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return _latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return _longitude;
}


public boolean IsInsideRegion(double latitude, double longitude)
{

    //Log.d("<GPD><POLY>","PR :" + String.valueOf(_pointList));

    Boolean result = false;
    if (_pointList != null && _pointList.size() > 0) {
        int Index1 = 0;
        int Index2 = _pointList.size() - 1;

        while (Index1 < _pointList.size())
        {
            if ((((_pointList.get(Index1).getLongitude() <= longitude) && (longitude < _pointList.get(Index2).getLongitude())) || ((_pointList.get(Index2).getLongitude() <= longitude) && (longitude < _pointList.get(Index1).getLongitude()))))
            {
                if (latitude < (_pointList.get(Index2).getLatitude() - _pointList.get(Index1).getLatitude()) * (longitude - _pointList.get(Index1).getLongitude()) / (_pointList.get(Index2).getLongitude() - _pointList.get(Index1).getLongitude()) + _pointList.get(Index1).getLatitude())
                    result = !result;
            }

            Index2 = Index1;
            Index1++;
        }
    }
    if (result)
        Log.d("<GPD><POLY>", "In Polygon Region:" + this.getId());
    return result;
}

private void calculateMinMaxLatLong(double aMinLatitude, double aMaxLatitude, double aMinLongitude, double aMaxLongitude)
{
    /*
    _minLatitude = 0d;
    _maxLatitude = 0d;
    _minLongitude = 0d;
    _maxLongitude = 0d;

    for (Point currentPoint: _pointList)
    {
        if (currentPoint.getLatitude() < aMinLatitude)
            _minLatitude = currentPoint.getLatitude();

        if (currentPoint.getLatitude() > aMaxLatitude)
            _maxLatitude = currentPoint.getLatitude();

        if (currentPoint.getLongitude() < aMinLongitude)
            _minLongitude = currentPoint.getLongitude();

        if (currentPoint.getLongitude() > aMaxLongitude)
            _maxLongitude = currentPoint.getLongitude();
    }*/

    double smallestLat = _pointList.get(0).getLatitude();
    double largestLat = _pointList.get(0).getLatitude();

    double smallestLong = _pointList.get(0).getLongitude();
    double largestLong = _pointList.get(0).getLongitude();

    for (int x = 0; x < _pointList.size(); x++){

        if(smallestLat > _pointList.get(x).getLatitude())
            smallestLat = _pointList.get(x).getLatitude();

        if(largestLat < _pointList.get(x).getLatitude())
            largestLat = _pointList.get(x).getLatitude();

        if(smallestLong > _pointList.get(x).getLongitude())
            smallestLong = _pointList.get(x).getLongitude();

        if(largestLong < _pointList.get(x).getLongitude())
            largestLong = _pointList.get(x).getLongitude();
    }

    _minLatitude = smallestLat;
    _maxLatitude = largestLat;
    _minLongitude = smallestLong;
    _maxLongitude = largestLong;
}
```

public RegionChecker()
    {}

```
public RegionChecker(boolean aEnterFirstOnly) {
    _enterFirstOnly = aEnterFirstOnly;
}

public List<Region> CheckGpsPosition(List<Region> aActiveRegion, List<Region> aRegionList, MyLocation aLocation, IRegionEventListener aListener) {
    List<Region> result = new ArrayList<Region>();
    Log.i("RegionChecker", "aRegionList " + String.valueOf(aRegionList.size()));

    boolean regionChanges = false;
    List<Region> overlappingPositionsList = new Regions().InsideRegions(aRegionList, aLocation.getLatitude(), aLocation.getLongitude());

    if (_enterFirstOnly)
    {
        if (overlappingPositionsList != null && overlappingPositionsList.size() > 0)
        {
            Region firstRegion = overlappingPositionsList.get(0);
            overlappingPositionsList.clear();
            overlappingPositionsList.add(firstRegion);
        }
    }

    Log.i("RegionChecker", "_activeRegions " + String.valueOf(aActiveRegion.size()));
    Log.i("RegionChecker", "overlappingPositionsList " + String.valueOf(overlappingPositionsList.size()));

    for(Region currentRegion: overlappingPositionsList) {

        Log.i("overlap check", String.valueOf(aActiveRegion.contains(currentRegion)));

        if (!aActiveRegion.contains(currentRegion)) {
            regionChanges = true;
            aListener.onRegionEnter(currentRegion, aLocation);
        }
    }

    for(Region currentRegion: aActiveRegion) {
           if (!overlappingPositionsList.contains(currentRegion)) {
               regionChanges = true;
               aListener.OnRegionExit(currentRegion, aLocation);
           }
    }

    result = overlappingPositionsList;

    if (regionChanges)
        aListener.OnCurrentRegionsChanged(result);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say it is failing?

Comment: What I got: I got a map and define a area of the street as being a region... When you enter the street/region it need to let me know by firing the onRegionEnter event above, when you leave the region or street it need to fire onRegionExit etc. In my case it never let me know about onRegionEnter.

Comment: Is your list always in an order such that you can draw lines from the 1st to the 2nd to the 3rd and so on and the lines never cross?

Comment: It will be better if you take some time to check your code and put here only the **relevant** parts of it. Run the methods with some well known values and check if the answer is the expected one, post the ones that do not work. Just dumping all the code makes more difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to modify your region checker.

- It should use longitude or latitude but not both. So it checks how many times a horizontal ray crosses the lines between vertices. Or it checks how many times a vertical line does.
- It needs to handle the point pairs and indices 0 & 1, 1 & 2 ... n-2 & n-1 and n-1 & 0.

I didn't see where you do that last pair, but there is a lot of code to read.